# Receiving interceptTouchEvent in ViewGroup

Tags: android

I have build a custom viewgroup like

```
public class InterceptorView extends ViewGroup {

    public InterceptorView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InterceptorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public InterceptorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        View view = getChildAt(0);
        view.layout(l, t, r, b);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.d(InterceptorView.class.getCanonicalName(), "y: " + ev.getY());
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int wspec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int hspec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View view = getChildAt(i);
            view.measure(wspec, hspec);
        }
    }
}
```

And inflated the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test.com.viewgroupexamples.InterceptorView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                            android:orientation="vertical"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentView"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</test.com.viewgroupexamples.InterceptorView>
```

I added 100 textviews dynamically so the scrollview can actually scroll.

With this setup I would expect the interceptTouchEvent to log even touchevent that happens. However I generally get the DOWN and a couple of MOVE events then it stops. Is this the correct behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So it transpires that there is a method within ViewGroup called requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent. This blocks the return onInterceptTouchEvent for the current gesture. This means the InterceptorView.onInterceptTouchEvent() was receiving the DOWN event then a couple of MOVE events until the touch slop was overcome and then Scrollview actually calls requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent when IT received MOVE in it's ontouch.

I was able to overcome this problem by overwriting the requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent method like so...

```
@Override
public void requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will notice that 'onInterceptTouchEvent()' returns a boolean. This is to signify that you are interested in the event (it has been 'intercepted'). If you don't return true for the initial DOWN event, this method will not be called for subsequent events. Careful though, because if you do this, the views lower in the hierarchy will not receive those events. In a nutshell, replace

```
return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
```

with

```
return true;
```

Comment: I think you are getting mixed up between the behaviour of onTouch() and and onInterceptTouchEvent. Look at my answer below and let me know what you think

Comment: Yeah, you're right.... I didn't actually check the docs, just wrote from memory. In reality, returning true in 'onInterceptTouchEvent' will cause the 'onTouchEvent' of the ViewGroup to be called for the original DOWN event AND the subsequent ones. Btw, that's where you are supposed to handle the events, and not in 'onInterceptTouchEvent'. Having said that, you can use 'requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent' as well, in order to get 'onInterceptTouchEvent' callbacks.